# Why is the absolute magnitude of a source negatively correlated to its luminosity?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy

The absolute magnitude $M$ of a source of luminosity $L$ is given by $M = -\frac{5}{2}log(L) + constant$. Why is $M$ defined with a negative correlation to the luminosity? Wouldn't it be more intuitive to have a larger absolute magnitude for a larger luminosity of the source?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the magnitude $M$ is such that smaller values correspond to brighter objects. Hence, the larger the luminosity $L$ the smaller the absolute magnitude $M$.